# Replace or disable OS X dns cache?

Tags: macos, dns, cache

I'm having [trouble with OS X's dns cacher](https://superuser.com/questions/326848/strange-ns-behavior-on-os-x-cant-connect-to-ssh-server) and I'm wondering if it's possible to simply disable it or replace it with a better / more configurable program?
I don't suppose it's as easy as deleting an executable somewhere, is it -- and if so, do you know which one?

Comment: Bump? Just searched and came across my own question, still with no answers :(

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?   Please give some more details regarding your issue and maybe someone will help you.   Is the problem the same exact one you are referring to in your other post?   Is your DNS server local?  If it is local, what DNS server software is it running?   Is your computer the only one having this issue?

Comment: @Richie086 regardless of what the issue is, the question as stated is simply "is it possible to disable or replace the default OSX DNS cache?"