# OSX: ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxxxx.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-catalina

I'm trying to ssh into my ec2 instance using:

```
ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@xxxxx.com
```

And I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xxxxx.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

This is not an ec2 problem because replacing `xxxxx.com` with `public-ip-address` works just fine.

This is also unlikely to be a DNS problem because:

1. `nslookup` for `xxxxx.com` returns the correct IP
2. I can SSH into the machine using the exact command above from *another ubuntu machine*

So this must be an OSX issue. Ping also doesn't work:

```
ping: cannot resolve xxxxx.com: Unknown host
```

I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/326848/strange-ns-behavior-on-os-x-cant-connect-to-ssh-server), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1147690/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-until-restart), everything [here](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/52722069.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n/33506923), and even just restarting my mac. Nothing helped.

What else can I do?

Comment: Is changing your upstream DNS resolver an option for you?

Comment: is xxxx.com a FQDN? what do you get when you do a `dig @8.8.8.8 xxxx.com` or `dig @1.1.1.1 xxxx.com` (resolving via Google & OpenDNS DNS servers)

Comment: Do you have multiple DNS servers configured on the Mac? If so, test all of them separately, and make sure they *all* resolve the host properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I recently changed the DNS settings of the domain and my local DNS provider didn't update their server as quickly as they usually do (took a couple days). So it wasn't OSX after all.

Anyone else running into this - check if you can access the domain from your phone (not on same wifi, use 3g), which might signal a similar issue.